# Rename Shelf Application Name

Tags: google-chrome, appmenu

Currently, on my sidebar shelf, my Google Chrome (when hovered over) displays: "Google Hangouts - *my email here*."

Not sure how this happened, possibly me accidentally pinning the application to my shelf while Hangouts was opened, but now from Search, the application is displayed as "Google Hangouts"

I looked in `/usr/share/applications`, and Google Chrome is there, named Google Chrome.

Where is this "Google Hangouts" name coming from/where is it stored, and how can I revert the shelf application and search application back to being named Google Chrome?